# How to trim last 4 characters of each elements present in an arraylist in java?

Tags: java, csv

I have imported a set of values into an array list from a csv file. Now i need to remove the extension .tar from each element or allow only first 8 characters to be inserted into the array list while importing it from a csv file. This is my code and i want that change in array1 part

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.*;


public class compare 
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>(); //Array for storing values
  ArrayList<String> array1 = new ArrayList<String>(); //Array for storing values

  try
  {
    String strFile = "D:\\Ramakanth\\PT2573\\ftp.csv"; //csv file containing data
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(strFile)); //create BufferedReader to 
    String strLine = "";
    StringTokenizer st = null;

    while( (strLine = br.readLine()) != null) //read comma separated file line by line
    {
     st = new StringTokenizer(strLine, ","); //break comma separated line using ","

     while(st.hasMoreTokens())
     {
      array.add(st.nextToken()); //store csv values in array
     }
    }
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
    System.out.println("Exception while reading csv file: " + e);                  
   }

   try
   {
    String strFile1 = "D:\\Ramakanth\\PT2573\\target.csv";  //csv file containing data
    BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(strFile1)); //create BufferedReader 
    String strLine1 = "";
    StringTokenizer st1 = null;

    while( (strLine1 = br1.readLine()) != null) //read comma separated file line by line
    {
     st1 = new StringTokenizer(strLine1, ","); //break comma separated line using ","

     while(st1.hasMoreTokens())
     {
      array1.add(st1.nextToken()); //store csv values in array
     }
    }
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
    System.out.println("Exception while reading csv file: " + e);                  
   }

   array.removeAll(array1);
   System.out.println(array);

   try
   {
   BufferedWriter br2 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\Ramakanth\\PT2573\\output.csv"));
   StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
   for (String element : array)
   {
    sb1.append(element);
    sb1.append(" ");
   }

   br2.write(sb1.toString());
   br2.close();
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
    System.out.println("Exception while writing csv file: " + e);                  
   }

  }
}
```

Comment: Why you are reading the file three times? Could you provide an example of the input and what do you expext as output?

Answer (score 0):

You can do by using [StringUtils.substringBefore](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substringBefore(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) class by using

```
StringUtils.substringBefore(yourstring, ".tar" );
```

It will give you the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    String element = "extension.tar";

    int index = element.lastIndexOf(".");
    System.out.println("if Dot extension means : " + element.substring(0, index));
    element = element.substring(0, 8);

    System.out.println("if first 8 character means : " + element);
```

**output:**

if Dot extension means : extension

if first 8 character means : extensio